# Could superconducting magnets be used to form a shield around a spacecraft?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, superconductivity, rocket-science, cryogenics

If superconducting magnets could be used in space to form a field around a spacecraft of a similar field strength on the earth 25 to 65 microtesla's?

1. Would the temperature in space at -246c be OK for superconducting magnets to work with no energy penalty?
2. Could the cryogenic fuel be used to help cool the superconducting magnets?

Comment: I wrote a page long answer, but I am not sure it wasn't a silly idea. You didn't put a point to the end of your sentences, why do you want a long and smart answer to your question?

Comment: I was thinking about space trips out side the earths magnetic field say to mars the astronauts would be exposed for up to 3 years , you could get some shielding from water carried on the ship but if you could generate a strong magnetic field around the ship it could offer some protection cosmical waves / partials

Comment: It is not so bad, the wall of the ship protects people in it against nearly 100% of the photons and the charged particles. It is much harder problem, what would they eat and breathe. See you, how I beautified your question? It is an important thing, if you are lazy to end your sentences with a mark, people will think you are also lazy to read their answers. And they will be right, you didn't read the answers (or, at least, you didn't react on them).

Comment: I know NASA is very worried about the shielding problem on long space flights as it has been found there can be substantial brain neuron damage this far out ways the problem of carrying about 4 tons of water and food at current estimates the space craft would be about 40 tons

Answer (score 3):

These schemes have been proposed and studied. A spacecraft with a magnetic field could steer charged particles away from it.

The magnetic field would have to be much stronger than the Earth's magnetic field. The reason is pretty easy to see. The Lorentz for $\vec F~=~q\vec v\times\vec B$ for the charged particle velocity perpendicular to the magnetic field gives circular motion
$$
m\frac{v^2}{r}~=~qvB
$$
and this gives the cyclotron radius of the charged particle 
$$
r~=~\frac{mv}{qB}.
$$
This equation holds for a constant magnetic field over the radius of this motion. For charged particles deflected by the Earth's magnetic field this condition approximately holds over thousand of kilometers. The Earth' magnetic field $B~\simeq~.5$Gauss is large and extensive in space. We are not able to do this.

For spacecraft applications you would need to deflect charged particles over a radius of about $10$ to $100$ meters. By just using ratios with the cyclotron radius above it is easy to see you would need a magnetic field on the order of $10^4$ to $10^5$ Gauss or $1~-~10$T. This is one or two order of magnitude smaller than the largest magnetic fields generated on Earth. So it would not be an easy technical feat.

Comment: If the space ship was made to spin this could be used to produce some artificial gravity field which could help to stop bone loss and by spinning the ship , the magnetic field would also spin would this help the field strength or would the field collapse?

Comment: Rotating the magnetic field will not change the field strength overall, but change its spatial configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The temperature in space is not as easy thing, because it is not clear, what is actually whose temperature we want to know. On the Earth, the temperature in the meteorology means the temperature of the air in shadow. But there is no air in the space. The cosmical microwave background has a temperature of around 2.7K, but it is -270C and not -246C.

But in the Solar System, or nearing a star, there are also the photons of the nearby star. Their energy distribution is not thermal, but we can assign a temperature to them by saying with which temperature they have a thermal equilibrium. On the orbit of the Earth, it is around +10C (not surprising - the Earth radiates exactly the same power, as it gets from the Sun. Or else it would be overheated or cooled down).

Short answer: Magnetic field shields only against charged particles, for example it would be practically negligable against laser weapons or against an electrically neutral space torpedo.

Yes, there are superconductors on -246C, but they are incapable to construct a really strong magnetic field. Industrial superconductors are cooled by liquid Helium until now.

Comment: Radiation can have temperature. The CMB, for instance, has a temperature of approx. 2.7K. Your environment indoors has radiation with roughly the temperature of the walls. When you go outside on a humid day it feels warmer because the humidity traps radiation at a higher temperature than the dry atmosphere.

Comment: @CuriousOne I cite my post: *"Their energy distribution is not thermal, but we can assign a temperature to them by saying with which temperature they have a thermal equilibrium."* It is for the photons coming from the Sun. The CMB *has* thermal distribution (which I also mentioned).

Comment: You are writing "...only matter can have temperature", which is clearly false.

Comment: So could the cryogenic fuel all ready carried on the ship be used to cool the superconductor magnets and when running would they have any energy penalty as the space craft will have a limited power supply.

Comment: @CuriousOne Oops, right. Fixed.

Comment: @GarryWilson Current space probes don't have cryogenic fuel, it is only used to leave the Earth. It has many reasons (one of them that they would evaporate very fast, and there is nothing with they could be cooled). Cooling things can be done only if you let some other things to be heated (for example, this is why the refrigerator in your kitchen is warm on its back side). In the space, it is going on the same way, although eliminating the heat is not so simple, because heat conduction doesn't work. It happens by radiating away the unneeded heat, this is what the ISS does.

Comment: @GarryWilson So, to cool the magnet, you need: 1: energy (on the current technology, it can come from decaying radioactive materials, mainly U238, or from solar panels), 2: you need a refrigerating machine 3: you need radiation panel to help to radiate the waste heat away.

Comment: @GarryWilson I suspect it could be done relatively easily, the mT field of the Earth is not so strong, it wouldn't even require superconducting wires. Although there are not so many charged particles there against them such defense would be required.

Comment: Would the temperature in space if in the shade be at a level where the superconducting magnets work OK and what is the highest temperature they can work at?

Comment: @GarryWilson If you shade out the Sun perfectly, then only the background of the light of the stars and the CMB will heat the probe. I don't know the exact data but I suspect around 10k (-260C) for the thermal equilibric temperate. It would be enough (btw, there are relatively strong superconducting magnets already on the temperature of the liquid air). You need to make a probe which is capable to work on -260C or to solve the next engineering problem: you should heat it to a working temperature while you still hold the low temp of the superconducting wire. I think it is not so easy

Comment: @GarryWilson as it seems but it is solvable. Also the solar panels of the probe could work as a shade. So your idea, on my opinion, could work. What is not clear to me: there are no Klingon ships out there bombarding our probes with proton beam. This defensive mechanism could work (_only_ against charged, not relativistically fast particles), but I can't see the attacker.

Comment: @GarryWilson Btw, what nears your problem at most: global superpowers are starting to play with technology to destroy eachothers satellites. They do this also not with charged beams, only by 1: with simple rockets (i.e. rocket which doesn't transfer nuclear bombs to the enemy territory, but simply stays before one of its artificial satellite), 2: by making their own satellites to cross the enemys. Don't forget: orbital speed on low earth orbit is around 8000 m/s, while a cannon fires only with around 600 m/s. And kinetic energy (= simple, mechanical destructive power) depends quadratically

Comment: @GarryWilson on the speed. There is no need for ion gun, simple kinetic energy is far enough to destroy anything. And magnetic shield wouldn't defend against it.